# How to switch between android source version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently it's not very intuitive how to switch between Android SDK source files in Android Studio while, for example, debugging or just inspecting the sources.

I've got the feeling that Android Studio, unlike IntelliJ, is getting the source's version from the compiled SDK version section of the Gradle configuration. But, this is forcing me to debug on a device which is using the same Android version when debugging. If I don't, then the sources won't be in sync with the debugger.

**My question:** Is there an easy way to switch between Android sources in Android Studio without having to change the configuration in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. `mv $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21 $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21-orig`
2. `cp $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-17 $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21`
3. Restart android studio so it will pick up the correct paths.
4. Debug

> [NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/android-source-swap) program to easily switch the Android SDK Sources which Android Studio attaches when debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it seems there is no built-in way in Android studio to select the Android source version to display, so the nodejs program you posted seems to be the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think studio grabs the Android SDK platform source from the targetSDKVersion.

It's wise to update the targetSDKVersion to the latest Android platform SDK from your SDK manager.

It's better for development if your project constraints you from increasing the targetSDKVersion grab the platform SDK your project mentions.

[Android platform SDK's](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html)